# Download files from google drive

Tags: ios, iphone, google-drive-api, ios9

In my app i have to show a list of docs from users google drive account. User will be able to download it.

I have implemented Google Drive ios sdk, successfully implemented login and also fetching the files.
But there is no download url to download the files.
Scope is kGTLAuthScopeDrive

In some stackoverflow posts i saw people posted downloadUrl property of GTLDriveFile. But in my SDK there is no such property.
Maybe they changed something in the latest SDK.

Need help here . I am really stuck at the moment.

Comment: What version of the Drive API are you using? v2 or v3?